# iOS: Get the maximum color of an image

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to get the maximum color of an image in terms of RGB, please suggest me solution for this.
i have searched it, but they provide solution using pixel colors and i am not getting it.

Comment: What is "maximum color of an image"? You need to write some code, that is what developing is all about. Think about exactly what you want to do, study the subject and try something, SO is here to help with *your* code. @Abhinav has provided base code showing how to access the individual pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not have raw image data you cannot directly find it. You would need to rely on pixels only. This is how colour of the image is deduced.

```
CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);

int pixelInfo = ((image.size.width  * y) + x ) * 4; // PNG

UInt8 red = data[pixelInfo];
UInt8 green = data[(pixelInfo + 1)];
UInt8 blue = data[pixelInfo + 2];
UInt8 alpha = data[pixelInfo + 3];
CFRelease(pixelData);
```

PS: There is nothing called maximum colour :)